# Simplifying expression containing Gamma

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

According to [this site](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma/24/01/) this expression involving `Gamma` is valid:

$$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\Gamma\left(\dfrac{k+z}{n}\right) = n^{\frac{1}{2}-z}(2\pi)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\Gamma(z)$$

However it seems that Mathematica cannot simplify it (at least not version 10.0). Is thre a way to enforce it?

Answer (score 3):

With version 12.1.0, for any positive integer value of $\,n\,$ you can use `FunctionExpand` to verify with

```
ex[n_] := Product[Gamma[(k - 1 + z)/n], {k, n}] ==
   Gamma[z](2Pi)^(n/2 - 1/2)n^(1/2 - z) // FunctionExpand
```

For example, `ex[3]` returns `True`. However, using
`ex[n]` does not evaluate to a truth value.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround:

$$\Gamma \left(\frac{k}{n}+\frac{z}{n}\right)=\frac{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{k}{n}+\frac{z}{n}+1\right)}{\frac{k}{n}+\frac{z}{n}}$$

```
$Version
(* 12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 9, 2020) *)

Product[Gamma[k/n + z/n + 1]/(k/n + z/n), {k, 0, n - 1}] // FunctionExpand

(* n^(1/2 - z) (2 \[Pi])^(-(1/2) + n/2) Gamma[z] *)
```

Comment: Even `Product[Gamma[k/n + z/n], {k, 0, n - 1}]` works in version 12.0.

Comment: +1 Working from the original form: `Product[Gamma[(k + z)/n], {k, 0, n - 1}] /. 
   Gamma[x_] :> Gamma[x + 1]/x // FunctionExpand // 
 Simplify[#, n > 0] &`

Comment: @user64494.If: `Product[Gamma[(k + z)/n], {k, 0, n - 1}]` dosen't work, but: `Product[Gamma[(k + z)/n] // ExpandAll, {k, 0, n - 1}]` works fine.